# Same page for startpage and archive?

Tags: taxonomy, archives, homepage

Is it's possible to have the startpage to also serve as an archive page?

The startpage has a lot of boxes for other different categories and taxonomies. For example this:

```
<div class="column box medium-box module">

    <header class="module-head"><h2>Art</h2></header>

    <ul class="posts-list">
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 6, 
        'post__not_in'   => $do_not_duplicate,
        'category_name'  => 'art'
    );
    $myposts = get_posts($args);

    foreach ($myposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
    $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;
    ?>
    <li>

        <?php get_template_part('template-parts/post/content', 'small'); ?>

    </li>
    <?php endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata();?>
</ul>

</div>
```

Now, I want the taxonomy to be added to the arguments when the page serve as archive page.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Taxonomy_Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) in WordPress WP_Query like that:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 6, 
    'post__not_in'   => $do_not_duplicate,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'art',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'country',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'france',
        ),
    ),
);
$myposts = get_posts($args);
```

you can add the "country" taxonomy to links as url parameters and get it when click the the like.

Comment: I'm not sure you understod me wrong. But I don't want country and category to be in the get query on startpage.

Comment: use `is_tax()` to identity the taxonomy page, if it returns true, we are on the taxonomy term archive page, include the category_name query arg.